# Channel Section with individual entry template and index templates?

Tags: craft3, channels

I am looking for suggestion on how to setup a resource section on a site I'm building. Here is the structure.

Resources - Index

Entry type of resources
Webinars 
-Webinar Entry (template for a single webinar)
-Webinar Index (all webinars)
Whitepapers
-Whitepaper Entry (template for a single whitepaper)
-Whitepaper Index (all whitepapers)
Ebooks
-Ebook Entry (template for a single ebook)
-Ebook Index (all ebooks)

I was originally thinking to this as a channel, but how to I create indexes for the entry types: webinars, whitepapers, and ebooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I've done this in previously is in your templates have a directory titled `Resources` and inside that directory another directory titled `_types`

Within the `_types` directory I will have the code to output the content based on the entry type. I would name each of those templates `ENTRY-TYPE-HANDLE.html`

The on your Resources index user the following:
`{% include "resources/_types/" ~ entry.type %}`

Comment: How to you handle index page for those entry types?

Comment: I actually think I figured out a way to make the index template. I just used the routing so for the route resources/webinars I pointed it to an index template for webinars.

Comment: @DanielleFrappier Just name your index templates the same as the entry type name, e.g: whitepaper.twig